# Is it possible to put validations in controllers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an additional member method (and a corresponding route) called download, for which I'd like to validate the existence of a password field.
Putting `:validates_presence_of :password` in my download method, I get an error claiming it's an undefined method.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can add errors to the model but validations live in the model. Check out the errors methods and [add_to_base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Errors/add_to_base) if you need to add errors in the controller for whatever reason.